# Generating all possible k-mers (string combinations) from a given list

Tags: python, string, list, combinations, permutation

I have a string `S` that is composed of 20 characters:

```python
S='ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV'
```

I need to generate all possible k-mer combinations from a given input k.

When `k == 3`, then there are 8000 combinations (`20*20*20`) and the output list looks like this:

```python
output = ['AAA', 'AAR', ..., 'AVV', ..., 'VVV'] #len(output)=8000
```

When `k == 2`, then there are 400 combinations (`20*20`) and the output list looks like this:

```python
output = ['AA', 'AR', 'AN', ..., 'VV'] #len(output)=400
```

When `k == 1`, then there are only 20 combinations:

```python
output =['A', 'R', 'N', ..., 'Y', 'V'] #len(output)=20
```

I know how to do this if the number `k` is fixed, like if `k == 3`, then I can do this:

```python
for a in S:
   for b in S:
      for c in S:
         output.append(a+b+c)
#then len(output)=8000
```

But the number `k` is chosen randomly.
I tried to use permutations, but it does not given me strings with repeated letters like `'AAA'`, but maybe it can and I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can use `repeat` argument for the number of `k`'s in your algorithm.

```
from itertools import product
...
list(product('ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV', repeat=2)) # len = 400
list(product('ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV', repeat=3)) # len = 8000
```

Bear in mind it returns tuples of characters as default, if you want strings instead, you can join using list comprehensions as below:

```
[''.join(c) for c in product('ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV', repeat=3)]
# ['AAA', 'AAR', ..., 'AVV', ..., 'VVV']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` and generate the random value for `k`:

```
import itertools
import random
S = 'ARNDCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV'
final_results = map(''.join, itertools.product(*[S]*random.randint(1, 10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate random integer V in range `0..L^k-1` where L is string length and k is length of k-mer.

Then build corresponding combination

```
V = Random(L**k)
for i in range(k):
    C[i] = A[V % L]       ///i-th letter using integer modulo
    V = V // L            ///integer division
```